# Trying to put working arcpy.SearchCursor code into a function

Tags: python, list, function, gis, arcpy

I have python code that uses arcpy.SearchCursor to look for unique values in a field (Native_Species, in my case), and put them into a list. Then I use list comprehension to remove None values,  sort the list, and print. This code works.

```
# Create empty list, use .SearchCursor to populate list with unique values
myList = []
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(monitoring)
for row in rows:
    if row.Native_Species not in myList:
        myList.append(row.Native_Species)

# Use list comprehension to remove None values in list
res = [i for i in myList if i]

# Sort list and print
res.sort()
print(*res, sep = '\n')
```

I would like to put this code into a function, where I can list only unique values across multiple fields in a given feature class. This is what I have tried:

```
def listUnique(fc, fields):
    myList = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row.fields not in myList:
                myList.append(row.fields)
        res = [i for i in myList if i]
        res.sort()
        print(*res, sep = '\n')
```

This gives me an error "'tuple' object has no attribute 'fields'".

How should I put my working code into a function, where I can specify a given input feature class, and a list of fields within that feature class, and get back a list of only unique values across those fields?

Thank you!

Comment: arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor return a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not real pretty.  Might be more useful to create a unique value list for every feature class column.  Hopefully this will give you some ideas to get what you need.

```
import arcpy

# set the workspace to the geodatabase the feature class is in
arcpy.env.workspace = r'\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb'

def uniqueValues(fc):
    # create a list of unique values from all rows and columns in a feature class
    #create an empty list to store all values in the feature class
    tableList = []
    #Get all values in the feature class and append them to tableList
    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(fc)
    for fc in fcList:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "*") as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                for value in row:
                    tableList.append(value)
    print('The list length of all values is ' + str(len(tableList)))
    # Create an empty list to store the unique values in the feature class
    uniqueList = []
    # use set to drop duplicates
    uniqueSet = set(tableList)
    print('The list length of unique values is ' + str(len(uniqueSet)))
    # put the items from the set back into a list.  add all values to the list as strings to avoid data type problems
    for item in uniqueSet:
        uniqueList.append(str(item))
    # remove none values from the list
    uniqueList = [i for i in uniqueList if i]
    # sort the list
    uniqueList = sorted(uniqueList)
    print(*uniqueList, sep = '\n')

# call the function and enter the name of the feature class as the parameter
uniqueValues('Enter Feature Class Name')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).